Z Depth Wave Art in Blender Compositor (Joy Division effect)
I'm looking to recreate the effect from this Photoshop tutorial:
https://youtu.be/cafn5fvvIIk?si=RTSC_UQ-T83RsqFB
The video covers the exact problem at 1:00, in which using the standard Displace node can sample the same pixels more than once. Photoshop's solution is to stretch the displacement, then apply it to each individual line, but this approach isn't possible without Repeat Zones in the Compositor.
The setup below makes a wave texture using Modulo, which gives a similar idea but has that issue with sampling lines more than once. I'm aiming for each line to be one contiguous line without going back on itself, like a graph. Anything that'd help would be appreciated 
Blend file for the composite setup below:



Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Added that now, although it only adds a basic wave in Compositing as is. It's a decent start though
